# angularjs need to get the number of filtered items

Tags: angularjs

I have a project in which im sorting data based on predefined conditions i.e. approved or pending. But i am also using a page selection. my problem is that i cannot get the correct amount of objects withing the program to display the proper amount of pages(there is always extra pages because it takes the full amount not the filtered amount) So i know i need to somehow get the number of filtered objects to show the correct amount of pages. Could someone please explain how?

Filter

```
               <select class="form-control" ng-model="filterType"
                ng-options="pages for pages in filterSelection"
                ng-change="filterAmount()"
                ng-init="filterType=filterSelection[1]">

            </select>
```

# Of sheets per page:

```
               <select ng-model="itemperpage"
                class="form-control" ng-options="pages for pages in selection"
                ng-init="itemperpage=selection[0]"></select>
            <pagination total-items="max" page="currpage"
                items-per-page="itemperpage" max-size="maxSize"
                class="pagination-sm" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
        </div>
```

actual table

```
        <table
            class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed col-md-1">
            <tr>
                <th>Employee Name
                <th>Period</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Regular Hours</th>
                <th>Overtime Hours</th>
                <th>Total Hours</th>
                <th>Attachment</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Approve</th>
                <th>Deny</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in (filteredItems = (timeSheets|filter:filterType))" ng-if="$index>=((currpage-1)*itemperpage) && $index<((currpage)*itemperpage)">
                <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.period}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.status}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.regHours}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.overHours}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.totHours}}</td>
                <td><div ng-controller=imageController
                        ng-init="init(employee.username)">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" "type="button"
                            ng-click="imageModal(employee.username,employee.period)"
                            value="View" />
                    </div></td>
                <td>{{employee.Client}}</td>
                <td><input class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block"
                    "type="button"
                    ng-click="approveTimesheet(employee.username,employee.period)"
                    ng-disabled="(employee.status=='approved')" value="Approve" /></td>
                <td><input class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block"
                    "type="button"
                    ng-click="denyTimesheet(employee.username,employee.period)"
                    value="Deny" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

solved by using

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in (filteredItems = (timeSheets|filter:filterType))"</tr>
and then in pagination using

<pagination total-items=filteredItems.length page="currpage"
                items-per-page="itemperpage" max-size="maxSize"
                class="pagination-sm" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
        </div>
```